# Multiple text parsing and writing using the while statement, the diamond operator <> and $ARGV variable in Perl

Tags: perl, text-parsing, diamond-operator

I have some text files, inside a directory and i want to parse their content and write it to a file. So far the code i am using is this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

#The while loop repeats the execution of a block as long as a certain condition is evaluated true

use strict; # Always!
use warnings; # Always!

my $header = 1; # Flag to tell us to print the header
while (<*.txt>) { # read a line from a file
    if ($header) {
        # This is the first line, print the name of the file
        **print "========= $ARGV ========\n";**
        # reset the flag to a false value
        $header = undef;
    }
    # Print out what we just read in
    print;
}
continue { # This happens before the next iteration of the loop
    # Check if we finished the previous file
    $header = 1 if eof;
}
```

When i run this script i am only getting the headers of the files, plus a `compiled.txt` entry.
I also receive the following message in cmd : `use of uninitialized $ARGV in concatenation <.> or string at concat.pl line 12`

So i guess i am doing something wrong and `$ARGV` isn't used at all. Plus instead of `$header` i should use something else in order to retrieve the text.

Need some assistance!

Comment: when i change the script either to `while (<STDIN>) {`  i am only permitted to input text from keyboard, either to `while (<>) {` i get an invalid argument error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<*.txt>` does not read a line from a file, even if you say so in a comment. It runs

```
glob '*.txt'
```

i.e. the while loop iterates over the file names, not over their contents. Use empty `<>` to iterate over all the files.

BTW, instead of `$header = undef`, you can use `undef $header`.

Comment: change to empty `<>` and `undef $header` instead of `$header = undef`. I run "`perl concat.pl *.txt > compiled.TXT`" and returned the following error: `Can't open *.txt: invalid argument at concat.pl line 9.`

Comment: @LDN-5602: Are there any `*.txt` files in your working directory? (Mind that "txt" is different to "TXT".)

Comment: there are some .txt files along with some perl scripts. TXT it is the file type of the output file name "compiled.TXT"

Comment: @LDN-5602: Works for me. Are you running exactly the code you posted? What OS are you on?

Comment: Windows 7 yes i am running the exact same code with the changes you proposed ofc.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand you want to print a header with the filename just before the first line, and concatenate them all to a new one. Then a one-liner could be enough for the task.

It checks first line with variable `$.` and closes the filehandle to reset its value between different input files:

```
perl -pe 'printf qq|=== %s ===\n|, $ARGV if $. == 1; close ARGV if eof' *.txt
```

An example in my machine yields:

```
=== file1.txt ===
one
=== file2.txt ===
one
two
```

Comment: Tried to run the above in cmd and got the following: `'%s' not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`